# Accept Hosted Recurring billing

Tags: authorize.net, authorize.net-arb

`getHostedPaymentPageRequest` only provides two types of transaction to generate a token for the form using the following XML.

Two transaction type:

1. authCaptureTransaction
2. authOnlyTransaction

```
<getHostedPaymentPageRequest xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
  <merchantAuthentication>
    <name>5KP3u95bQpv</name>
    <transactionKey>346HZ32z3fP4hTG2</transactionKey>
  </merchantAuthentication>
  <transactionRequest>
    <transactionType>authCaptureTransaction</transactionType>
    <amount>20.00</amount>
    <profile>
      <customerProfileId>123456789</customerProfileId>
    </profile>
    <customer>
      <email>ellen@mail.com</email>
    </customer>
    <billTo>
        <firstName>Ellen</firstName>
        <lastName>Johnson</lastName>
        <company>Souveniropolis</company>
        <address>14 Main Street</address>
        <city>Pecan Springs</city>
        <state>TX</state>
        <zip>44628</zip>
        <country>USA</country>
    </billTo>
  </transactionRequest>
  <hostedPaymentSettings>
    <setting>
      <settingName>hostedPaymentReturnOptions</settingName>
      <settingValue>{"showReceipt": true, "url": "https://url-when-continue-button-clicked/receipt", "urlText": "Continue", "cancelUrl": "https://url-when-cancel-button-clicked.com/cancel", "cancelUrlText": "Cancel"}</settingValue>
    </setting>
    <setting>
      <settingName>hostedPaymentButtonOptions</settingName>
      <settingValue>{"text": "Pay"}</settingValue>
    </setting>
    <setting>
      <settingName>hostedPaymentStyleOptions</settingName>
      <settingValue>{"bgColor": "blue"}</settingValue>
    </setting>
    <setting>
      <settingName>hostedPaymentPaymentOptions</settingName>
      <settingValue>{"cardCodeRequired": false, "showCreditCard": true, "showBankAccount": true}</settingValue>
    </setting>
    <setting>
      <settingName>hostedPaymentSecurityOptions</settingName>
      <settingValue>{"captcha": false}</settingValue>
    </setting>
    <setting>
      <settingName>hostedPaymentShippingAddressOptions</settingName>
      <settingValue>{"show": false, "required": false}</settingValue>
    </setting>
    <setting>
      <settingName>hostedPaymentBillingAddressOptions</settingName>
      <settingValue>{"show": true, "required":false}</settingValue>
    </setting>
    <setting>
      <settingName>hostedPaymentCustomerOptions</settingName>
      <settingValue>{"showEmail": false, "requiredEmail": false, "addPaymentProfile": true}</settingValue>
    </setting>
    <setting>
      <settingName>hostedPaymentOrderOptions</settingName>
      <settingValue>{"show": true, "merchantName": "G and S Questions Inc."}</settingValue>
    </setting>
    <setting>
      <settingName>hostedPaymentIFrameCommunicatorUrl</settingName>
      <settingValue>{"url": "https://url-contianing-iframe"}</settingValue>
    </setting>
  </hostedPaymentSettings>
</getHostedPaymentPageRequest>
```

How should I modify the XML so that I can get the form for recurring billing? As I did not find any implementation example in accept hosted to get a valid form token for recurring billing. There was not mention of recurring billing the accept hosted documentation.

Also, I am using the redirect method and not the iframe one to display the form which does not return any response as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no one form for creating a subscription through the hosted form. Fortunately someone already [posted how to do this on their forum](https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/Create-Customer-Payment-Profile-Subscription-with-Accept-Hosted/td-p/64311) which I will repost here:

> If you are trying to use the Accept hosted forms for creating a
>   subscription, you actually wouldn't use the hosted payment page,
>   described [here](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/accept_hosted.html).
>
> The correct workflow is, using the API, make a request for a customer
>   profile: `createCustomerProfileRequest`. All you need is their email
>   address.
>
> After getting the profile id from that call, you make a request for a
>   token for the accept hosted [add profile form](https://accept.authorize.net/customer/addPayment). Documentation for
>   this form and others is [here](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/customer_profiles.html).   I didn't even realize these forms
>   existed. It's hard to find them in google even if you know what you're
>   looking for.
>
> You need the customer profile id to get the token for the "add payment
>   profile" form.
>
> You handle the response to this form client-side since you are getting
>   the response from the IFrameCommunicator page you set up (it works the
>   same for the payment form or these customer profile type forms).
>   [Here's a sample](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/accept-sample-app/blob/master/IFrameCommunicator.html).
>
> I then called server-side code to create the subscription with the api
>   - I pass it the customer profile id because honestly I don't know if the form returns the newly created payment profile id. If you have the
>   customer profile id, you can retrieve any existing payment profiles.
>   So, using just the customer profile id, I make a call to get the
>   payment profile id - `getCustomerProfileRequest`. That call returns
>   all sorts of stuff including the payment profiles. I just grab the
>   first one.   Now with the customer profile id and the payment profile
>   id, I can create a subscription - `ARBCreateSubscriptionRequest`.
>   There are samples out there to help you form the subscription
>   properly.
>
> Final note: if you are testing this in the sandbox, you will need to
>   put a 20 second delay between obtaining a payment profile id and
>   obtaining a subscription using the api. The sandbox does not have the
>   resources to handle these transactions real time. Figuring that out
>   cost me several hours.  You can read through this post to confirm, and
>   though it's older, it is still true:
>
> https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/E00040-when-Creating-Subscription-from-Customer-Profile/m-p/59597#M34176

Comment: Thanks @John for your comment as it helped me to get a better direction to implement authorize.net form in a modal and it does not have a problem with recurring billing as well. 

I was able to implement this using the following script "https://jstest.authorize.net/v3/AcceptUI.js". The development description are on the following URL: https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/acceptjs.html#Building_your_Payment_Form.

Just putting this information, if in case anybody wants to add authorize.net for in place of his own form.

Comment: If this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answer-er and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.